# Active Directory Group Policy Automatically Removed Overnight

Tags: windows, server, active-directory, group-policy

In our Active Directory we have a group policy to allow users to manage the server via Remote Desktop.

I have to apply this to my user EVERYDAY because it seemingly removes itself overnight on it's on. 5:30 pm yesterday it was working properly. Today (no reboot) I login and the remote connection says the permission is missing.

Has anyone experienced this and can anyone help?

Comment: Are you the administrator of the domain? Have a look at the "Restricted Groups" settings in your GPOs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are applying it to the correct user group?

I’ve had trouble in the past with this, being a novice. I would suggest doing running the following from command prompt Gpresult /h report.html /f

This will generate a HTML document that you can see what has been applied to this machine. If it’s not on there then it’s probably a wrong target from the GPO end. If it’s there but fails you should have a reason why.

One more thing to check too is what your GPOs are on your computer itself. there might be something that is overwriting/blocking what the AD is sending?

Comment: So, I originally added the remote desktop permission to my user account. It stays on fine and apparently for no reason just get's removed overnight. It shows in Gpresult when I first apply it, but when I run it the next day it's always gone from the list. I have duplicate permissions to another user whos do not become removed overnight.

Comment: Anything in Task Scheduler? Or logon scripts?

Comment: And to confirm you have no other users with this issue? Is this user you or was 'my user' referring to one of the users you look after?

Comment: Issue was fixed, there was a global GP preventing Remote access.

Comment: @MercPls glad you got it sorted!